# How to extract variables from a equation?

Tags: c++, math

Im studying some code and I would like help with some math. Im trying to solve the equation of the tangent line on a circle with given point of tangency.

```
//(x1 - p)(x - p) +(y1 - q)(y - q) = r^2 I understand this formula
//variables
//x1 = point.x
//y1 = point.y
//p  = center.x
//q  = center.y
//r  = radius
```

edit: here is the whole function, maybe it will help. My teacher gave it to me to study, but maybe he is trolling me :D

```
const std::pair<double, double> Arc::tangentEquation(const glm::vec3& center, const glm::vec3& pointA, float radius) const {

  if (radius <= 0.0f)
    throw std::domain_error("Radius can't be negative or 0");
  // Jednadžba tangente u točki T
  // (x1 - p)(x - p) + (y1 - q)(y - q) = r^2
  glm::vec3 point = pointA + center;

  double px = -1 * (center.x * point.x);
  double qy = -1 * (center.y * point.y);
  double x = point.x - center.x;
  double y = point.y - center.y;
  double k = 0.0;

  double l = (pow(radius, 2) - (px + pow(center.x, 2) + qy + pow(center.y, 2)));

  if (y == 0) { // paralelan s x os
    k = l / x;
    l = 0;
  } else if (x == 0) { // paralelan s y os
    l = l / y;
    k = 0;
  } else {
    k = -x / y;
    l = l / y;
  }
  return std::pair<double, double>(k, l);
}
```

Comment: why write it so long like that? and the `-1*` is redundant because just a simple minus will work

Comment: i think it reffers at the extraction of x from the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not implement the formula on the first line, so I don't think it is strange that you don't understand :-)

```
(x1 - p)(x - p) + (y1 - q)(y - q)
```

If we write out all the terms in the parenthesis multiplication, we get:

```
x1*x - p*x - p*x1 + p^2 + y1*y - q*y - q*y1 + q^2
```

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s_lroR5_1U for very pedagogic explanation)
But your code looses half of these terms....?

Comment: Maybe you have defined the problem in such a way that some coordinates are always = 0 ?

Comment: No that was a stupid suggestion, if px and py != 0 then all coordinates are != 0. Where did you get the equation from?

Comment: p and q are 0 i guess, yea, i tried now, the center is always (0,0) so its not a stupid suggestion!! so it can be writen only l = radius^2 lol

Comment: Ah, well in that case... :-)

Comment: can you explain me how he got the formula for l? l = l/y? @JesperWe

Comment: Well, a line is y = k*x + l.  A circle with center (a,b) is (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2. And then you solve for l. And its second degree so you get a lot of special cases, which you handle in the if statement. Here is a good resource if you want to dive into it: http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-circles-2009-1.pdf